# Change div position with translate3d according to the mouse movement

Tags: jquery, html, css, mousemove

I would like to achieve the effect of subtil div position changes with css transform translate3d according to the mouse movement.
Something like the geometric figures of this website home section:
http://riccardozanutta.com/

I tried this:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
  $(".home-img").css({"left" : event.pageX, "top" : event.pageY});
});
```

with a single image positioned absolute and it worked (the image changed position according to the mousemove), however when I try to animate 3 divs with class .basic-skill

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
  $(".basic-skill").css({"left" : event.pageX, "top" : event.pageY});
});
```

they go out of the view port (when they are positioned relative) or they overlap one another (when they are positioned absolute).

Moreover, I don't know how to limit the movement to max 5 px instead of making it move all over the view port.

Thanks a lot for your guidance!

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving your question for the max 5px displacement, you can multiply the X and Y coordinates with a factor like 0.1 to reduce the amount of movement. Like so:

```
$(".basic-skill").css({"left" : event.pageX * 0.1, "top" : event.pageY * 0.1});
```

**EDIT:** Instead of using `top` and `left`, you can use `margin-top` and `margin-left` with a static `top` and `left` value in CSS. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcoy5xpg/1/)

CSS

```
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
```

JS

```
$("#two").css({"margin-left" : -(event.pageX * 0.1), "margin-top" : -(event.pageY * 0.1)});
```

**EDIT 2:** Enhanced Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qcoy5xpg/2/

But this is just a quick n easy one. In the demo page you provided, he has used CSS animations on SVG elements. That is why it seems elegant, if I may (easings)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a possibility to add a movement to the current css position? I believe that your solution resets the position of my elements to the default;